# How to load profile specific files when the profile is set conditionally and programmatically?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Let us say you have two profiles `ping` and a dependent profile `pong`. The `ping` profile is optional. I want to add the `pong` profile if the `ping` profile is set and other programmatically checked conditions are true. See full [sample Springboot Application](https://github.com/sandipchitale/progprofiles) repo.

```
package sandipchitale.progprofiles;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationStartingEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.env.Profiles;

import java.util.Arrays;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProgprofilesApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplicationBuilder()
//              .listeners((ApplicationListener<ApplicationStartingEvent>) event -> {
////                    event.getSpringApplication().setAdditionalProfiles("ping");
//                  if (event.getSpringApplication().getAdditionalProfiles().contains("ping")) {
//                      // Programmatically add the "pong" profile if ping is active
//                      event.getSpringApplication().setAdditionalProfiles("pong");
//                  }
//              })
                .initializers(  (ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) -> {
                    ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
                    if (environment.acceptsProfiles(Profiles.of("ping"))) {
                        // Programmatically add the "pong" profile if ping is active
                        environment.addActiveProfile("pong");
                    }
                })
                .sources(ProgprofilesApplication.class)
                .build();
        springApplication.run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner clr (Environment environment) {
        return (args) -> {
            String[] activeProfiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();
            System.out.println("Active Profiles = " + Arrays.asList(activeProfiles));
            // Check if this activates application-pong.properties
            System.out.println("pingpong=" + environment.getProperty("pingpong"));
        };
    }
}
```

and config files:

application.properties

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
spring.profiles.active=ping
#spring.profiles.active=ping,pong
logging.level.root=INFO
pingpong=notset
```

applocation-ping.properties:

```
pingpong=ping from application-ping.properties
```

and application-pong.properties:

```
pingpong=pong from application-pong.properties
```

When I run the code I get this output:

```
[           main] s.progprofiles.ProgprofilesApplication   : The following 2 profiles are active: "ping", "pong"
[           main] s.progprofiles.ProgprofilesApplication   : Started ProgprofilesApplication in 1.617 seconds (process running for 2.715)
Active Profiles = [ping, pong]
pingpong=ping from application-ping.properties
```

As you can see the `pong` specific profile file did not get loaded.

If I set the `pong` profile in application.properties file like so:

```
spring.profiles.active=ping,pong
```

Then application-pong.properties file loads and I get the output:

```
Active Profiles = [ping, pong]
pingpong=pong from application-pong.properties
```

I tried to set the `pong` profile using both `SpringApplication.listener()` and `SpringApplication.initializer()` but the `application-pong.properties` file did not load.

How to handle this?

Comment: Why don't you start them via cli `java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=ping,pong`? or using Unix environment, profiles can also be activated via the environment variable `export spring_profiles_active=ping,pong`

Comment: I want to check some additional conditions programmatically before setting the `pong` profile. I did not show that in the example but mentioned it.

Comment: `envs` variables include the system variables and business variables, system variables are required at the startup application, your additional conditions could be in `CICD` part. Otherwise, you can use `@Conditional` to create bean for business variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think two ways impl it

1. you can specify spring.config.import=classpath:application-pong.properties directly in the applocation-ping.properties configuration file
2. in initializer load resource

   ```
        .initializers((ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) -> {
            ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
            if (environment.acceptsProfiles(Profiles.of("ping"))) {
                // Programmatically add the "pong" profile if ping is active
                environment.addActiveProfile("pong");
                try {
                    Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(applicationContext.getResource("classpath:application-pong.properties"));
                    environment.getPropertySources().addAfter("systemEnvironment",new PropertiesPropertySource("application-pong",properties));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //ignore
                }
            }
        })
   ```

Of course, neither of the above two methods requires setting environment.addActiveProfile("pong");

If you still want to put the configuration file in the file system, just change the classpath prefix to file prefix.

Comment: Ah...so we have to do this ourselves. Spring Boot will not help here. I was under the impression that adding profile should do the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can specify spring.config.import=classpath:application-pong.properties directly in the applocation-ping.properties configuration file

Comment: What if I want to have the file on the filesystem so that the users can edit the `application-pong.properties` file?

Comment: spring.config.import=file:/opt/config/application-pong.properties